# Same method for the Functions Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

```
def function1(string):
    symbol="%"
    new_string=string.split()
    for item in new_string:
      if item.startswith(symbol):
         #etc

def function2(string):
    symbol="!"
    new_string=string.split()
    for item in new_string:
       if item.startswith(symbol):
         #etc
```

The above functions do same thing except the symbols are different, so i want to create an extra function(dont know how to do it) that would accomplish what im trying to do and  then call it inside both of the functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that, if both functions perform the exact same operation you only need one function with `symbols` as an extra argument:

```
def function(string, symbol):
    new_string=string.split()
    for item in new_string:
      if item.startswith(symbol):
         #etc
```

Then call it as `function("foo", "%")` and `function("bar", "!")` respectively.

Comment: for my assignment, i need to have two functions, one for getting strings that start with % and the other for string starting with !